# Best way to calculate co-occurences matrix over a rolling windows in scala spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a very large dataset with 'user_id', 'event_id' and 'event_date'.

What would be the most efficient way in scala spark, to calculate the events' co-occurence matrix, with a co-occurence being counted only if happening within a window of say n days for a particular customer ?

| user_id | event_id | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 01/01/2000 |
| 1 | 101 | 05/01/2000 |
| 1 | 102 | 14/05/2021 |
| 1 | 103 | 20/05/2021 |
| 2 | 100 | 04/06/2001 |
| 2 | 101 | 10/06/2001 |
| 2 | 102 | 13/08/2021 |
| 2 | 103 | 30/08/2021 |

So, if we consider a 15 days window, for each user we obtain the following co-occurences:

| user_id | event_id_1 | event_id_2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 | 101 |
| 1 | 102 | 103 |
| 2 | 100 | 101 |

Hence, finally the total number of co-occurences:

| event_id_1 | event_id_2 | count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 101 | 2 |
| 102 | 103 | 1 |

That's the process I need to run in Scala Spark. Any suggestion?
Many thanks in advance

Comment: It's always good to share how does input and output looks like to set a correct expection

Comment: can you add input data and expected output ?